# Service failing to run because of "Permission Denial", permission required is null

Tags: android, android-manifest

My program has been running fine, but I think I must have accidentally changed something I shouldn't have done. I had my program running "UpdateService" on the press of a button, but now it doesn't run, and debug brings up the following two lines:

```
01-05 21:43:39.945: WARN/ActivityManager(98): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=10084
01-05 21:43:39.955: WARN/ActivityManager(98): Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{com.android.datausagemonitor/com.android.datausagemonitor.UpdateService} from pid=98, uid=1000 requires null
```

Here is my manifest, judging by similar posts it could well be a problem with this, but I can't see it and am pretty sure I haven't changed anything since it was last working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.android.datausagemonitor"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".DataUsageMonitorActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <service android:name="com.android.datausagemonitor.UpdateService"></service>
    <service android:name="com.android.datausagemonitor.ResetService"></service>

</application>
```

Comment: can you show the service code?

Comment: Can you provide the code that calls it?

Comment: Problem solved, I restarted the phone I was running the app on. Something to do with the Uid messing up. Wasted 3 hours on this! lol

Comment: Write your answer in and mark is as corrected

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help anyway

Comment: thanks Matt, your question (and solution) saved me 3 hours :) had the same problem, googled, rebooted -- and it worked. cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Solved] There was some problem with the Uid between Eclipse and the device I was testing on. Rebooting the device solved the problem.