# Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED

Tags: android, permissions, sms, broadcastreceiver, manifest

Hello i am new to Android, I'm getting this problem even after having the required SMS permissions inside my manifest file. I tried a couple of ways but it doesn't work anymore got any idea?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.phonefinder2"
        android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />    
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">


        <activity android:name=".PhoneFinder" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".FinderReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"> 
            <intent-filter > 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" android:priority="999"/> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error:

```
07-19 19:23:25.915: D/SntpClient(66): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
07-19 19:23:29.444: W/ActivityManager(66): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=10042
07-19 19:23:29.454: W/ActivityManager(66): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED (has extras) } from com.android.phone (pid=124, uid=1001) requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to receiver com.example.phonefinder2/com.example.phonefinder2.FinderReceiver
07-19 19:23:29.544: V/Telephony(235): getOrCreateThreadId uri: content://mms-sms/threadID?recipient=83380222
07-19 19:23:29.616: V/Telephony(235): getOrCreateThreadId cursor cnt: 1
07-19 19:23:30.126: D/Mms:app(235): getSmsNewMessageNotificationInfo: count=19, first addr=83380222, thread_id=1
07-19 19:23:30.194: W/NotificationService(66): STOP command without a player
07-19 19:23:30.305: D/MediaPlayer(66): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-19 19:23:30.334: E/MediaPlayerService(34): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
07-19 19:23:30.334: E/MediaPlayer(66): Unable to to create media player
07-19 19:23:30.354: W/NotificationService(66): error loading sound for content://settings/system/notification_sound
07-19 19:23:30.354: W/NotificationService(66): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
07-19 19:23:30.354: W/NotificationService(66):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
07-19 19:23:30.354: W/NotificationService(66):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:716)
07-19 19:23:30.354: W/NotificationService(66):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:671)
07-19 19:23:30.354: W/NotificationService(66):  at com.android.server.NotificationPlayer$CreationAndCompletionThread.run(NotificationPlayer.java:88)
```

FinderReceiver.java:

```
package com.example.phonefinder2;

import android.app.Notification;   
import android.app.NotificationManager;   
import android.app.PendingIntent;   
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;   
import android.content.Context;   
import android.content.Intent;   
import android.content.SharedPreferences;   
import android.location.Location;   
import android.location.LocationManager;   
import android.os.Bundle;   
import android.telephony.SmsManager;   
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;   
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FinderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "Logging Activity";

    Context context;   
    @Override    
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        Log.v(TAG, "New Broadcast Receiver");
        this.context = context;   
        SharedPreferences passwdfile = context.getSharedPreferences(    
                PhoneFinder.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY, 0); 

        Log.v(TAG, PhoneFinder.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY);

        String correctMd5 = passwdfile.getString(PhoneFinder.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY,    
                null);    

        Log.v(TAG, correctMd5);

        if (correctMd5 != null) {    
            Log.v(TAG, "MD5 is not null");

            if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
              Log.v(TAG, "Intent SMS RECEIVED success");
              Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();   
              if (bundle != null) {
              Object pdus[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
              SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];   

//              for(int i = 0; i < smsMessage.length; i++)
              for(int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {   
                  smsMessage[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);   
                if (smsMessage[i].getMessageBody().contains("RING:")) {    
                    String[] tokens = smsMessage[i].getMessageBody().split(":");    
                    if (tokens.length >= 2) {    
                        String md5hash = PhoneFinder.getMd5Hash(tokens[1]);    

                        if (correctMd5.equals(md5hash)) {    
/*                            String to = smsMessage[i].getOriginatingAddress (); 
                            SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault(); 

                             sm.sendTextMessage (to, null, "success!", null, null);
                            NotificationManager nm =  
                                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
                            Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, "Alert", System.currentTimeMillis());
                            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity (context, 0, new Intent (context, PhoneFinder.class), 0);
                            notification.setLatestEventInfo (context, "GPS address", "You have been detected", contentIntent);
                            nm.notify (R.string.service_start, notification);*/
                            this.abortBroadcast();
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Ring success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
                            toast.show();
                        }    
                    }    
                } 
                }   
            }    
    }
        }
}    
}
```

Comment: can you post the code where you are trying to access SMS?

Comment: Can you post the entire logcat of the crash - 2 lines will not suffice!

Comment: just did it, don't really think the rest of them are relevant to it tho

Comment: The only thing that I can think of right now is doing a null check on bundle. if (bundle != null) {} but I'm not sure why that would do anything.

Comment: also, you should add some debug statements to see what is going on before the crash...

Comment: tried it but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Look! this is turning into a guessing game! Debug it yourself! We cannot do it all for you! [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix it by changing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.phonefinder2" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <activity android:name=".PhoneFinder" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".FinderReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"> 
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>

     </application>

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hey I am having the same error. What did you change? I am not sure I have understood

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<receiver android:name=".FinderReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"> 
<intent-filter> 
  <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" android:priority="999"/> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

To:

```
   <receiver android:name=".FinderReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"> 
  <intent-filter> 
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" android:priority="999"/> 
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

You need the permission tag in the receiver as well.

Edit:

Change the property android:exported="false" to android:exported="true"

Comment: Yeah, tried that too. I even added a few debugging logs inbetween but it seems like it doesn't even reach the logs

Comment: yea, probably the bundle!=null changed it

Comment: yup, i telnet a sms message to the android emulator and i get this error

Comment: Check out the solution to this question. Maybe it has more to do with the first error on there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750365/service-failing-to-run-because-of-permission-denial-permission-required-is-nu

Comment: Rebooting the eclipse and android emulator doesn't seem to help :(

Comment: change android:exported="false" to true. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858549/permission-denial-even-after-adding-the-correct-permission-in-the-manifest its "required as you are receiving a broadcast that originates from outside your own application. "